# Getting Error at the time of cropping the image

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, croppie

basically what I'm doing is an admin panel and in this section, the user can upload images and also updated the images. when the user clicks on an image a model will load up with the selected image and below there will be a choose new image button when the user clicks on that they can update the image

I am getting below error at the time of cropping the image

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'singleInst.result')

I'm using croppie to crop images.

```
<div class="row">
                        <?php $count = 0;?>
                            <?foreach ($get_specials as $display_specials): ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $display_specials['id']?>">
                                <div class="main-card mb-3 card" >
                                    <div class="card-header"><?=$display_specials['name'];?></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$display_specials['name'];?>" name="hidden_name<?=$count?>" id="hidden_name<?=$count?>"/>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <img src ="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/specials/<? echo $display_specials['image'];?>" style = "width:100%" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">Click on the image to browse</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                             <!--Edit Special Modal Start-->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?=$display_specials['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit <?=$display_specials['name'];?></h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                                       
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class = "container">
                                                <div class = "row">
                                                    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
                                                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                                                        <img src ="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/specials/<? echo $display_specials['image'];?>" style = "width:100%" >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12" style="">
                                                <div id="upload-demo-i<?=$count?>"></div>
                                            </div>
                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?=$display_specials['id'];?>" name="edit_id<?=$count?>" id="edit_id<?=$count?>"/>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                                                    <label for="validationTooltip02">Product Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" id = "edit_name<?=$count?>" name="edit_name<?=$count?>" value = "<?=$display_specials['name'];?>" required>
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" id = "edit_oldname<?=$count?>" name="edit_oldname<?=$count?>" value = "<?=$display_specials['name'];?>">

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                                                    <label for="validationTooltip02">Cost Rs</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cost Rs" id = "edit_price<?=$count?>" name="edit_price<?=$count?>" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" value = "<?=$display_specials['cost'];?>" required>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-12 textarea__field">
                                                    <label for="validationTooltip02">Product Discription</label>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Add Body" id = "edit_discription<?=$count?>" name = "edit_discription<?=$count?>"><?=$display_specials['discription'];?></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <div class="position-relative row form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                        <label for="validationTooltip02">Add a new image</label>
                                                        <input name="editimage<?=$count?>"  id = "editimage<?=$count?>" type="file" class="form-control-file">   
                                                        <input type="hidden" id="checkimage<?=$count?>" name="checkimage<?=$count?>" value="<? echo $display_specials['image'];?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                            
                                                <div id="upload-demo2<?=$count?>" name="upload-demo2<?=$count?>" style="width:350px"></div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                           
                                            <button class="btn btn-info edit-result<?=$count?>" type="submit">Edit</button>
                                      
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $count++; ?>
                        <!--Edit Special Modal End--> 
                            <?endforeach?>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?=$count;?>" name="count" id ="count"/>
</div>

<script>
                      var count = $("input[name='count']").val();
                        //var y = 1;
                        

                    for(var z = 0; z < count; z++){
                        
                        $uploadCrop2 = $("#upload-demo2"+z).croppie({
                            
                            enableExif: true,
                            viewport: {
                                width: 350,
                                height: 200,
                                type: 'rectangle'
                            },
                            boundary: {
                                width: 360,
                                height: 210
                            }
                        });
                            
                        $("#editimage"+z).on('change', function () { 
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                $uploadCrop2.croppie('bind', {
                                    url: e.target.result
                                }).then(function(){
                                    console.log('jQuery bind complete'+z);
                                });
                                    
                            }
                            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        });
                        console.log("count of z is = "+z)
                    }
                        
                   
                        $(".edit-result"+z).on('click', function (ev) {
                            
                            $uploadCrop2.croppie('result', {
                                type: 'canvas',
                                size: 'viewport'
                            }).then(function (resp) {
                                for(var y = 0; y < count; y++){

                                //console.log('hellow');
                                var error = 0;
                                
                                var edit_id = $("input[name='edit_id"+ y +"']").val();
                                var edit_name = $("input[name='edit_name"+ y +"']").val();
                                var edit_price = $("input[name='edit_price"+ y +"']").val();
                                var edit_discription = $("textarea[name='edit_discription"+ y +"']").val();
                                var editimage = $("input[name='editimage"+ y +"']").val();
                                var checkimage = $("input[name='checkimage"+ y +"']").val();
                                var edit_oldname = $("input[name='edit_oldname"+ y +"']").val();
                                console.log(edit_name);
                                console.log("hellow"+y);
                                if(edit_name === "" || edit_price === ""){
                                    error++;
                                    html = '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-danger fade show" role="alert">Make sure you have fill the data</div></div>';
                                    $("#upload-demo-i"+ y +"").html(html);

                                }else{
                                    for(var x = 0; x <= count; x++){
                                    var hidden_name = $("input[name='hidden_name"+ x +"']").val();
                                    //console.log(hidden_name);
                                        if(edit_name === edit_oldname){
                                    

                                        }else if(edit_name === hidden_name){
                                            error++;
                                            html = '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-danger fade show" role="alert">Name is already taken</div></div>';
                                            $("#upload-demo-i"+ y +"").html(html);
                                        }
                                    
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                               
                                //console.log(error);
                                if(error===0){
                                    $.ajax({
                                    url: "update/specials_update",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {"image":resp, edit_id:edit_id, edit_name:edit_name, edit_price:edit_price, edit_discription:edit_discription, "editimage":editimage, "checkimage":checkimage},
                                    error: function(data) {
                                        html = '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-danger fade show" role="alert">There was an error</div></div>';
                                        $("#upload-demo-i"+ y +"").html(html);
                                    },
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        //html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
                                        html = '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="alert alert-success fade show" role="alert">The product was succesfully added</div></div>';
                                        $("#upload-demo-i"+ y +"").html(html);
                                        //setTimeout("window.location.href='specials';",1000)
                                    }

                                });
                                }
                                //console.log(y);  
                            }
                            });
                        });
<script/>
```

Comment: Mention what is your problem in question? Where you getting Error ??

Comment: I'm getting the error when I select a image to crop

Comment: I think you are getting javascript error

Comment: Actually your code is `comment less` and I have never used `croppie` before so It is really hard to tell the error occured due to your JS code or croppie code

Comment: You are using `count` in for loop in JS. But what is the value of count in JS

Comment: the value of `count` is the amount products available in the database